# Summarizing a custom query (WooCommerce)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

The following query returns one line for each product in woocommerce orders joined with it's order details, line_total (sold price) and owner.

owner is a custom field that tells me who is the vendor of the product and I get it's value using a sub-query as follows:

```
SELECT *, 
   (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta meta WHERE order_item_id = items.order_item_id AND meta.meta_key LIKE '_product_id') AS product_id, 
   (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta meta WHERE order_item_id = items.order_item_id AND meta.meta_key LIKE '_line_total') AS line_total, 
   (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'product_owner' AND post_id = product_id) AS owner
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items items, wp_posts orders
WHERE orders.ID = items.order_id
HAVING owner LIKE 'someownername'
```

The above query is working great and the thing that I need to do is to summarize the output of the above query to show only the following:

```
Year Month, Total Sales
2017 January, 3211
2018 February, 4553
...
```

orders.post_date field should be used to get the year and month, while line_total should be used to get paid summary.

Any help?

Comment: If you only need Total sales by date and month, product_Id wise then you have to use a little bit of PHP for looping and 2 MySQL query _here I can help_. But if you need to get the full details by SQL query only then you have to post with the table structure and sample data to [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions) site to get quick response. Because WordPress/WooCommerce developer hardly write custom SQL query.

Comment: Raunak, I think I figured some way to do it using LEFT JOINs instead of sub-queries. Thanks anyway for your kind comment.